# Check the presence of a message type in protoBuf

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-net

I am new to gRPC and wanted to check the presence of a message field in the C# language. I know that we can use the hasField() property in Java but there is no mention of any such property in C#.

```
message foo
{...}

message bar{
foo data=1;
}
```

How can I check whether the data field in message bar is set or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless marked as `optional`, the field **will** be present in every message.

See [optional](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview?hl=en#optional)

The fields in `data` (type `foo`) may be unset, in which case defaults are used. See the language [guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial).

> **NOTE** Your question concerns protobufs (the messages that are sent) not gRPC (the RPC mechanism) specifically.